# How to make my vote button store cookies in database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

[This](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/36/)
is my upvote/downvote button. Now i want it to store cookies in the database of my website. But i am not familier with that. So can someone help me? 
Currently i am using a localstorage script which is also bugged and not working.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<div id="buttons">
<div type="image" class="buttonup" id="plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></div><span id="count">0</span>
<div type="image" class="buttondw" id="minus" style="vertical-align:middle"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttons{
width: 100%;
height: auto;}
.buttonup {
padding: 0px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 0px;
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png');
}

 #count {
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 0px;
 background-color: #33cc33;
 border: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 50px;
 margin-top: 0px;

 }

 .buttondw {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 0px;
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png');
}

 .buttonup:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png")
}
 .buttondw:hover {
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png")
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var counter = 0, // Try change this what ever you want
 votePlus = counter + 1,
  voteMinus = counter - 1;

function checkIfUserVoted() {
 return localStorage.getItem("voted");
 }
 if (!localStorage.getItem("voted")) {
 localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
 $("#count").text(counter);
 }
 $(".buttonup").click(function() {
 var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != votePlus ? votePlus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).next().text(vote);
 });
 $(".buttondw").on('click', function () {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != voteMinus ? voteMinus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).prev().text(vote);
  });
```

Comment: Short answer: use AJAX. Long answer: use AJAX and process the ajax data on your server. how you do that depends on your database and server language. Your question is too broad to give you a specific answer.

Comment: For almost every possible server stack there are many tutorials to be found. You first task is to decide what kind of server you want to use. But [SO] is not the place for recommendations.

Comment: Hmm..actually i am newbie javascripter, can you guys give me more idea and advise? .

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Make sure you can identify the user (for instance by him or her needing to be logged in before being able to vote) through a session (lookup what a session is if you need to).

**Step 2:** Make sure you can identify whatever the user is voting on by the means of a unique identifier (have a question table in your database, assuming people are voting on questions).

**Step 3:** When a user votes, send an ajax request (lookup how to send a post request with javascript or jQuery) containing the questions id. Now you know who the user is and what question he voted on, so you can store this information into a table.

Now if you do all this, you can then identify whenever you're loading a page whether or not the current user has already voted on the question. If a user manages somehow to still vote, you need to check on your server again if he already voted, and only allow him to if he hasn't voted on the specified question yet.